# Dynamic creation of tab with iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I am creating tabs dynamically when an user clicks a menu. The referenced html file is opened within a iframe which is also created dynamically.

Everything worked fine but When the tab count exceeds '**3**' and the user clicks on the previous tab the next iframe gets displayed below the previous iframe content.

Below is the code i used. Can anyone suggest what should i do ?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html><head>
<script text/javascript>
$(document).ready(function() {
       var c=0;
       $("#documents a").click(function() {
       c++;
       addTab($(this),c);
       return false;        
       });

    $('#tab1 a.tab').live('click', function() {
        // Get the tab name
            i = 0;
            var chk;
            var contentname = $(this).attr("id") + "_content";

        var ifid=$("#content .dcontent:last iframe").attr("id");

            // hide all other tabs
            if(ifid>1)
            {
            for(i=ifid;i>0;i--) 
                {
                    fr = document.getElementById (i);
                    if (fr.style.display!='none')
                    {
                        fr.style.display="none";
                    }   
                }  
            }    

        //make the current frame visible 
        var lnm=$(this).attr("name");

        fr = document.getElementById (lnm);

        if (fr.style.display=='none')
            fr.style.display="block";

        $("#tab1 li").removeClass("current");

        // show current tab
        $(this).parent().addClass("current");

    });
});

/* Creation of Tab*/ 
function addTab(link,ct) {

    // If tab already exist in the list, return
   if ($("#" + $(link).attr("rel")).length != 0) 

return;

    // hide other tabs
$("#tab1 li").removeClass("current");

   if(ct>1)
   {
            for(i=ct-1;i>0;i--){    
                fr = document.getElementById (i);

                if (fr.style.display!='none')
                    fr.style.display="none";
            }  
   }

    // add new tab and related content
   $("#tab1").append("<li class='current'><a class='tab' id='" + $(link).attr("rel") + "' name='"+ct+"' href='" + $(link).attr("href") + "' target='" + $(link).attr("target") + "'>" + $(link).html() + "</a><a name ='"+ct+"' href='#' class='remove' >x</a></li>");

    var e = $('<div class="dcontent" ><li style="list-style:none;"><iframe id="'+ct+'" src='+$(link).attr("href")+' name="content" align="middle" width=600px; height=400px;> </iframe></li></div>');

    $('#content').append(e);   
}
</head>
    <body>

        <ul id="tabs">
            <!-- Tabs go here -->
            <div style="float: left;">
                <ul id="menu">                                
            <li> <a href="#">Next</a>
               <ul id="documents">
                        <li><a href="tab1.html" target="content" rel="1" >Document4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="tab2.html" rel="2"  target="content" >Document5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="tab3.html" rel="3"  target="content" >Document6</a></li>
                           <li><a href="tab4.html" rel="4"  target="content" >Document6</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </div>
        </ul>
        <ul id="tab1">
            <div style="float: left;">     
        </ul>

        <div id="content">              
        </div>
```

Comment: `DIV > LI` is invalid html. `LI` must be child of a list element

Comment: Possibly I am misreading, but it looks like all you want is the content to update with the current tab. If that is so instead of $('#content.append(e); you can use $('#content').html(e);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A major issue is the way your IDing your elements. You have a variable **c** which is numeric, starting at 0, increases whenever a link is clicked, and then is set as the ID as one of your iframes. However, you are also setting numeric IDs to the created tabs. Eventually, these element IDs will overlap and you will have errors like these.

At the very least, make your iframes have the ID of

- "frame_" + $(link).attr("rel")
- rather than the **ct** numeric variable you are using now (copy of **c**)

so that an example ID may be "frame_2" for the button with *rel* attribute of 2. That way you won't have a button with *rel* attribute of 2 connected to some frame with a random numeric ID.

Get rid of the **c** variable completely.

Instead of this loop:

```
if(ct>1) {
    for(i=ct-1;i>0;i--){    
        alert(i);
        fr = document.getElementById (i);

        if (fr.style.display!='none')
            fr.style.display="none";
    }  
}
```

use:

```
$("#content").children("div.dcontent").each(function() {
    var theFrame = $(this).find("li iframe");
    if ($(theFrame).attr("id") != ("frame_" + $(link).attr("rel"))) {
        $(theFrame).css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

That way you can easily link the *rel* attribute to the frame's ID, rather than an arbitrary numeric value from your **c** variable.

You should use your *rel* attribute for everything, since you've given your links that. You could use use something like *data-buttonid* and use .data() to access it, but that's up to you.

Then when you ID everything, use that number to pair everything together. i.e.

- Frame ID: "frame_" + $(link).attr("rel")
- Tab ID/Name: "tab_" + $(link).attr("rel")
- A Name: "tab_anchor_" + $(link).attr("rel")

Testing with the code I provided resulted in it executing how you want.